# Focus Lab's EE Master Config Error with MAMP

Tags: focus-lab-master-config

I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Config::site_prefs() in ...Dev/cms/ee.dev/system/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php on line 122`

My setup is as follows: MAMP, EE 2.10.1

```
ee.dev
- config
- public_html
- system
```

`Dev` is my MAMP `htdocs` folder and I have custom virtual hosts setup as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Dev/cms/ee.dev/public_html/"
  ServerName ee.dev
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/Dev/cms/ee.dev/public_html/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

I was originally getting another error, so I updated the system paths in the main `index.php` and `admin.php`:

Changing `$system_path = './system';` to `$system_path = '../system';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use the sample config file from that repo. Here's the issue you seem to be experiencing https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config/issues/2

Comment: Thank you. That solved it! 

Although now seems to be loading database templates. It's something to do with the base path. 

My setup is: `ee.dev/public_html/templates/`

And in `config.master.php`:

`$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath']        = $base_path . '/../templates';` 

I tried a few different paths but can't seem to get it working :s

Comment: so `$base_path` your document root but `$base_path . '/../templates';` is going a level up. If you move your template directory a level above, that should solve your issue. I'd always recommend getting to know the default config file first before working with master config.

Comment: Ah right, yes makes sense. I tried that but didn't seem to work. Confused as to what should be in the master config file vs the system config file now :(

Comment: Solved it here :) - http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32892/focus-lab-master-config-vs-system-config/32900#32900 - thanks for your time!